# Pass multiple parameters from ajax post to asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a view that I'm binding with knockoutjs. I need to add data dynamically to a list in the viewmodel using ajax post.

```
            var data = {
                model: ko.toJS(self.Model),
                name: name
            }

             $.ajax({
                url: options.url + "AddAdvantage",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    self.UpdateOnChange = false;
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.Model);
                    self.UpdateOnChange = true;
                }
            });
```

when the data parameter is passed to the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddAdvantage([ModelBinder(typeof(AdvantageModelBinder))] AdvantageViewModel model, string name) {
}
```

name value is passed, but model is always null

I have tried this:

```
            var data = {
                model: ko.toJSON(self.Model),
                name: name
            }
```

also tried:

```
            var data = JSON.stringify({
                model: ko.toJSON(self.Model),
                name: name
            });
```

same result.

this works fine:

```
           $.ajax({
                url: options.url + "AddAdvantage",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: ko.toJSON(self.Model),
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    self.UpdateOnChange = false;
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.Model);
                    self.UpdateOnChange = true;
                }
            });
```

My ModelBinder

```
public class AdvantageModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    public AdvantageModelBinder()
    {
    }

    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("WizardType");
        Type typeByTypeName = AdvantageModelBinder.GetTypeByTypeName((string)value.ConvertTo(typeof(string)));
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeByTypeName);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => obj, typeByTypeName);
        return obj;
    }

    public static Type GetTypeByTypeName(string typeName)
    {
        Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)assemblies.Length; i++)
        {
            Type type = assemblies[i].GetType(typeName, false, true);
            if (type != null)
            {
                return type;
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Can't find the specified type in the loaded assemblies.", typeName);
    }
}
```

can anyone tell how to fix this?

Comment: Is the value of ko.toJS(self.Model) is an js object?

Comment: Did you try to debug the `AdvantageModelBinder`? Also why are you calling `WizardModelBinder` inside `AdvantageModelBinder`

Comment: I'm not calling WizardModelBinder, it was a pasting error.

Comment: If ko.toJS(self.Model) is js object, then try this - var data = ko.toJS(self.Model); use this url - options.url + "AddAdvantage?name="name

Comment: Yes, Karthik that works, But I didn't want to pass it as a query string because in some instance, I might be passing up to six parameters.

Comment: @Alex it never calls AdvantageModelBinder if I pass something like this: var data = {
                model: ko.toJSON(self.Model),
                name: name
            }. it is only called when only  ko.toJSON(self.Model), is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're not passing exactly the same object in the payload.

Let's say that your model object is like this:

```
{
   foo: 1,
   bar: 2
}
```

On the first two samples you are creating this object:

```
{
   model: {
             foo: 1,
             bar: 2
          },
   name: "whatever"
}
```

So, when you pass it as an argument to the ajax call you're passing an object that is not expected on the MVC side.

If you want to store it in a variable, you need to do the following:

```
 var data = ko.toJSON(self.model)
```

And make the ajax call doing this:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: options.url + "AddAdvantage",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data,
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                self.UpdateOnChange = false;
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.Model);
                self.UpdateOnChange = true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = {
  model: self.Model,
  name: name
}

$.ajax({
  url: options.url + "AddAdvantage",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: ko.toJSON(data),
  traditional: true,
  success: function (data) { ... }
});
```